# Cross platform native games with Visual Studio

Tags: android, ios, visual-c++, mobile, sfml

Please note that I looked through all of the Visual Studio documentation for an optimum solution but I couldn't find any info :-)

I am going to develop my new game and this time I want to use C++ and Visual Studio. The game will run on iOS and Android and desktop. I work on a Mac Book Pro and run Windows and OS X on my computer simultaneously (with the help of VMWare Workstation).

The game will run on OpenGL ES with the help of some other frameworks (SFML). I'm trying to gather information on how to setup my solution and how should I use platforms specific APIs.

I assume I have to use **OpenGL ES Application (Android, iOS)** for the game itself and **Shared Library (Android, iOS)** for the game engine code.

Now comes the question, where should I put platform specific implementations including but not limited to:

- In-App Billing for Android
- In-App Purchases for iOS
- Chartboost/AdColony SDK for Android and iOS
- Some iOS-Only features implemented in Obj-C code

Basically I need to find a way to setup my projects in Visual Studio. I think I need to set up like this:

**Game Engine Project (Shared Library):** This will hold the game engine code that'll be shared on all platforms (let's assume only iOS and Android for the sake of simplicity).

**Shared Interfaces Project (Shared Library):** This will hold the shared interfaces for the platform specific API calls, like in-app purchases, etc. This project will only include the interfaces, not the actual implementations.

**Android Project (OpenGLES Application):** An Android native project to run the game on Android devices. This project will hold the Android implementations for the interfaces defined in the shared project.

**iOS Project (OpenGLES Application):** Similar to the previous one, only for iOS.

I don't know if the solution architecture is correct. If it is, how should I implement the iOS specific features. I know I need to use XCode for this. Do I have to create an XCode project on Mac and develop the iOS feature there using the Shared Library projects?

I'm really confused :-)

Comment: You can always get the platform where your game will be running in run time mode. So check the platform and write specific code.

Regarding the Obj-C code you can check methods to bridge the code.

Comment: It's not only about finding out the platform. It's about setting up platform specific projects and their interactions.

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement?

Comment: @JobinsJohn I updated the question, thank you.

Comment: Barring something I don't understand, this architecture should work. If you have installed and configured the tools to build using iOS, then created an OpenGLES 2 Application project in Visual Studio, you'll see it's created the boilerplate Xcode project for you in VS. This gets copied over to your Mac to be built. If you edit the code on the Mac, you need to copy it back into your VS solution for the build process there to work. If you install [Objective-C for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC) it's a bit friendlier to work on the iOS code in VS.

Comment: @ColinRobertson Yes, I created the project and installed vcremote. Visual Studio nicely created the necessary projects. It would be great if the compilation on OS X went smooth but I still have no luck in that, but that's the subject of another question I guess :-)

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit The template boilerplate iOS code should "just work" for any recent combination of OSX and Xcode versions. If you are having trouble, please post a comment or a question (a question is better if other people may run into the issue). If I can't help, I know the folks who work on this stuff, and I'll bring it to their attention.

Comment: @ColinRobertson Thank you! Here's a link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884087/opengles-application-android-ios-on-visual-studio