# OpenGLES Application (Android, iOS) on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cross-platform, xcode7

I created a cross platform OpenGLES application solution on Visual Studio. I paired Visual Studio with vcremote on my Mac. I can successfully compile the solution. When I switch to XCode and open the project which VS 2015 generated and build it I get the following error:

```
Ld /Users/elodie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSAndroGame.iOS.Application-cgfyoibpjigxohbhicqhmkivhjhs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSAndroGame.app/iOSAndroGame normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/elodie/vcremote/C/Users/elodie/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/iOSAndroGame/iOSAndroGame/iOSAndroGame.iOS.Application"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/elodie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSAndroGame.iOS.Application-cgfyoibpjigxohbhicqhmkivhjhs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/elodie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSAndroGame.iOS.Application-cgfyoibpjigxohbhicqhmkivhjhs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/elodie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSAndroGame.iOS.Application-cgfyoibpjigxohbhicqhmkivhjhs/Build/Intermediates/iOSAndroGame.iOS.Application.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSAndroGame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iOSAndroGame.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 /Users/elodie/vcremote/C/Users/elodie/Documents/Visual\ Studio\ 2015/Projects/iOSAndroGame/iOSAndroGame/iOSAndroGame.iOS.StaticLibrary/Debug/x86_64/libiOSAndroGame.iOS.StaticLibrary.a -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/elodie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSAndroGame.iOS.Application-cgfyoibpjigxohbhicqhmkivhjhs/Build/Intermediates/iOSAndroGame.iOS.Application.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSAndroGame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/iOSAndroGame_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/elodie/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSAndroGame.iOS.Application-cgfyoibpjigxohbhicqhmkivhjhs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOSAndroGame.app/iOSAndroGame

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/elodie/vcremote/C/Users/elodie/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/iOSAndroGame/iOSAndroGame/iOSAndroGame.iOS.StaticLibrary/Debug/x86_64/libiOSAndroGame.iOS.StaticLibrary.a'
```

Any ideas on why XCode can't find the static library?

Comment: You've probably already gone exploring in the file system and discovered this: When I built something similar, the portion of the path you've labeled x86_64 is just x64 on my machine, e.g.: `/Users/elodie/vcremote/C/Users/elodie/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/iOSAndroGame/iOSAndroGame/iOSAndroGame.iOS.StaticLibrary/Debug/`x64`/libiOSAndroGame.iOS.StaticLibrary.a` - this is an artifact of the build configuration. Does the project build from within VS?

Comment: Yes it's built successfully. I just can't open the XCode project. I already noticed that x86_64 naming scheme but don't know it's cause.

Comment: Ugh. I can't get the problem to repro on my system, but I may have more recent VC++ bits than you do. I asked my connections, and the answer appears to be, add the prebuilt static library `libiOSAndroGame.iOS.StaticLibrary.a` as an extra linker command line input dependency. Apparently Xcode doesn't build the referenced C++ shared code project `iOSAndroGame.Shared` because it's not a vanilla Xcode project (although it worked for me). The real answer might be to wait a couple of weeks for more iOS support in the next update to VC++, and try again.

Comment: @ColinRobertson Yes, I thought so. Meanwhile I already started coding my game so I hope everything goes fine for cross-platform support for VC++ :-) Thanks for the help.